# CSS: last child element's height should be based on previos siblings but not overflow parent

Tags: css, overflow

Relevant JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arosen/FMQtR/

## Problem

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id='parent'>
  <div id='one'>
    A variable amount of text here.
  </div>

  <div id='two'>
    A less important variable amount of text here.
  </div>
</div>
```

The #parent div is a fixed height and cannot change. Within it, I have at least two child divs. The first one (or many) will have an unknown amount of text in it determining its height. Based on the content of the first one, I want the last one to take up as much height is left in the parent but not overflow.

My current example CSS is:

```
#parent {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
  #one, #two {
    border: 1px dashed #333;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

## My current JS solution

```
function() {
  var $two = $('#two');
  var $parent = $('#two').parent()
  $parent.css('overflow', 'hidden');
  var heightDifference = $parent[0].scrollHeight - $parent.height();
  $two.css('height', $two.height() - heightDifference);
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a CSS layout or HTML solution to this problem or if I must use the JS solution I have in the fiddle that is run on the push of the last button.

**EDIT** Updated my JS fiddle as the text will **not** change once on the page but depending on information loaded from the server, will not know how much text it will have until the page is rendered.

**EDIT 2** Only modern (and IE 9) browsers need to be supported.

**EDIT 3** The final div **must** have a height as it is used by other jQuery plugins.

Comment: At first I dind't understand the question, but i agree with MrSlayer ...

Comment: What if the first element has as much content as the parent box  extents? Your fiddle is the solution to your question, when having `overflow: hidden;` enabled!?

Comment: Accidentally deleted my comment, when I went to edit it...because `div1` has variable height, I think the only solution is to use JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I've updated the fiddle. The design of the site and text for the first div makes it incredibly unlikely that div#one will take up the entire parent. There should almost always be some variable amount of room for div#two.

Comment: While I, and my office mates, believe @MrSlayer to be right, I'm hoping there's some kind of CSS/HTML sorcerer on stack who will have a magical solution :-)

Comment: @Aaron add Javascript tag and jquery tag for your question then the javascript and jquery followers will answer you :)

Comment: What sort of browser support do you need? Only modern browsers? IE7? Also, what does the actual design look like? You could make it *look* right with something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/FMQtR/20/.

Comment: @SureshPattu look at his fiddle he has js solution but he wants css solution if any which i don't think there is any

Comment: @thirtydot: Nifty, however, if the height of all container is less then `#parent` the border will still be shown.

Comment: Why is everybody trying to tag this question [javascript][jquery]? Just because the OP added in a JavaScript snippet?

Comment: Ok, all purists will probably kill me and blame my family for 100 generations, but table seems to be an easy way to achieve such a layout, isn't it ?

Comment: thirtydot's solution is good as long as there isn't borders involved, if it's a background colour it would work well

Comment: The borders are just to show where the elements are and their sizes.

Comment: @Aaron ok so you basically need to add another element in the parent so it blocks the space at the bottom and you should have what you are looking for. Use thirtydot's concept, as long as you are able to edit the html and css, his solution is best imp

Comment: Seems sort of like a problem that `flexbox` would want to solve, except that second div's content is already there which blows up `box-flex`. Same thing for `display:table`.

Comment: @Huangism the problem with thirtydot's solution is that it doesn't adjust the height of the last div to how much space it has to fill in the parent.

Comment: @Aaron you are right but in the view of the browser, it looks like it and that's all you need. Unless you need to get that height to do something. But you should not need the height since you do not want to use JS

Comment: The height is used by other jQuery libraries to either truncate text or put in a custom scroll bar.

Comment: If you're using that much JavaScript/jQuery on the page, it's not really worth embarking on a heroic mission to replace your current JavaScript solution with a CSS solution; particularly because there isn't an easy CSS solution :)

Comment: @thirtydot I agree. We were just very curious around the office as it seemed like this _should_ be something possible (albeit complicated) in HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can't. CSS isn't a programming language. Instead every `selector{ property:value; }` tuple defines a rule for a specific set of elements. The actual style such as current height, current width or other properties cannot be accessed in CSS.

Someone might think "what about percentage values"? Well, those are based on the containing block, which is often the parent element (in this case `#parent`).

So you either have to specify a fixed height for all `div` (which isn't possible according to the information you gave us), or use a JavaScript based solution.

Comment: the borders does not have to be there and I think he can edit his html/css so thirtydot's solution is good

Comment: I have to agree that after much discussion, it seems the JS solution is the only way to achieve exactly what I need to happen on the page.

Comment: @Aaron: The problem is that CSS doesn't offer any `get and modify` functionality, except for `attr()` and `calc()`, although the later isn't supported by any browser and likely to be dropped (see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/).

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this if you're not too set on borders/margin/padding/line-height. Just make sure that (parent div - (all margins/padding)) is wholly divisible by your line-height, you'd never see partial lines or overflow. However, with your border styles you can't achieve this through CSS alone.

You could still hack it by adding another element to the parent div, say a paragraph tag with the dashed border-top, and a thick white bottom border, positioned to hide the overflowing border with the above solution... but that's hacky, which I'm not a fan of, and has a potential to break easily across browsers.

TL;DR - Just use your JS.